# How do I make my prompt text on Embark Console visible?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, ethereum, embark

I'm trying to use Embark Console by Status.  I'm trying to do that on a Mac using Terminal.  The text I enter is invisible.  Whenever I type elsewhere on console, I can see it just fine.

Would appreciate any advice on how to fix this.

[Issue demonstrated in video hosted on Youtube](https://youtu.be/0hf8Fv_QTWA)

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved the issue.  Had to resize the terminal window and magically the text changed color.  If I'd paid attention properly, I would have seen the friendly advice inside the console.
Bah.